# Browser session cookies stolen/copied to another PC, why websites not smart enough prevent it?

Tags: cookies

Just out of curiosity and security test, i copied my own browser's cookies to another pc on same browser and surprisingly i managed to open facebook and google accounts with existing sessions even after public ip changed!!

Imo, it would be more secure if websites was clever enough to detect you r accessing an existing session from same platform/agent but from a combination of different ip/mac/machine model/unique id etc. in this case even if sessions stolen, only combination of same platform/agent/ip/user/any unique id that is related to actual user would be able to continue existing session. wouldnt it be good protection againts session hijackings? cheers

Comment: Some do respond to changes in the user agent. But generally the effort is put into protecting the session identifiers or limiting the damage caused if they were breached (ie short lived sessions). Filtering on IP isn’t very practical since many users will change IPs for the same computer throughout the day.

Comment: Of the things you mentioned: IP is likely to be the same for your two machines, if you were in the same building - you're likely being NATted when you go out the door.  Which may also be done by your ISP as well.  Note that residential IPs tend to change frequently, so this might cause you to log in every day.  MAC address will not be visible to the server.  Machine model isn't visible to the server, if it even exists (what is it for a home-built machine?).  Any competent attacker can spoof any provided value, except for possibly the IP.

Comment: web sessions are stateless meaning is somebody gets your sessions id cookie, they can sign in as you, Most sessions in web programming languages work this way. It's the programmers job to "lock" down a session id to a IP/useragent combination.

Answer (score 3):

There is always a balance between usability and security. There are some changes which might be perfectly normal, like visiting the same site from a totally different IP address (mobile users), with a slightly different User-Agent (might be caused by browser update), from a slightly different operating system fingerprint (might be caused by OS update or changes on hardware or restoring system from backup) etc. Getting cookies invalidated in these cases would be more secure but would also be annoying for the user.

But binding sessions to specific environments is also done in practice in cases where the sessions are short-lived so that the environment could be treated as kind of constant or where the data are very sensitive and it is acceptable to login again on any changes to the environment.

On the other hand: what you did is to explicitly copy the cookie from the browser into another browser. This is not what an attacker could do if the site is properly protected (HTTPS, http-only cookies) and the attacker has no physical access to your system. Insofar  binding a cookie to an environment should be more seen as an additional protection layer in case the other layers somehow fail (which they hopefully don't) and not as the single layer which protects against session theft.

Comment: "This is **not** what an attacker could do if the site is **properly protected (HTTPS**" What do you say here? https does **not** protect against code vulnerabilities **ever**, https **only** encrypts the data between server and client to prevent man in the middle attacks and eavesdrops, If client requests a SQL injection, uses Cross Side Scripting or tryes to fix the session id and the application is vulnerable the application will still execute with the vulnerability

Comment: @RaymondNijland : I did not claim that https protects against application vulnerabilities nor did the context of the question were application vulnerabilities.  https protects  against stealing the session by sniffing the network. http-only cookies instead help against session stealing misuing application vulnerabilities.

Comment: When i readed "This is not what an attacker could do if the site is properly protected (HTTPS, http-only cookies) and the attacker has no physical access to your system" it did look like that is what you meant that https protected against every application vulnerabilities . "https protects though against session stealing by sniffing the network." That statement is very true. 
"http-only cookies instead help against session stealing misuing application vulnerabilities. " Yes but only if the browser supports it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: all relevant browsers support http-only cookies for ages. Any browser which is that old or special to not support these is likely a security risk by itself.

Comment: "all relevant browsers support http-only cookies for ages. Any browser which is that old or special to not support these is likely a security risk by itself" sounds more or less security by obscurity into trusting that every internet user is using the modern browsers which support http only cookies..  it's not enough you should also regenerate your session id atleast at login level (or every request might be even better but more resource hungery but can cause trouble with AJAX requests) so session id fixing and session hijacking are not possible..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: This is not security by obscurity but assuming that the user is doing his part too. Not to use outdated software is part of a responsible behavior and such a thing is expected from adult persons. The alternative would be to block any users which use outdated software. Responsible behavior is not only expected in IT security but also in "real life". You don't expect anybody to use a car without working brakes, do you?

Comment: "Not to use outdated software is part of a responsible behavior and such a thing is expected from adult persons." tell that to someone who only knows how to turn on the PC and can use the internet, thats is a pretty large number, you have forgotten the average users which might not even know how to update outdated browser software.. So blocking updating browser might not be a very good thing to do unless you add update instructions on your website/application..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: the common current browsers all update themselves.

Comment: "current browsers all update themselves." jet again assumming all (average) users are running a modern OS and or browser which updates them self.. Windows XP, Windows 7 users might still be out there somewhere, Microsoft wlll stop making updates for Windows 7 in 2020..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: correct, I expect the average user should take care of the computer he uses the same way he takes care of his car. If the user is not willing to do this he faces the same kind of problems he faces when not taking care of the car, and rightly so.

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you introduce the requirement "The user may use archaic software", we pretty much have to throw up our hands and say that we give up. It's not possible to secure old software, because it's... old.

Comment: *"we pretty much have to throw up our hands and say that we give up. It's not possible to secure old software, because it's... old"* @vidarlo true the best we can do on webapplications to block old software is fingerprinting the browser (and OS maybe), block access and give the user update instructions assuming the browser is offcource not autoupdating.. But offcource this is not 100% trustworthy because you need to scan the browsers useragent string or use javascript to fingerprint..

Answer (score 1):

Because its very inconvenient for very little gain. Being able to copy the session cookies from your computer would be a very difficult attack that is on a similar level to being able to log your password as you type it. Its a safe enough assumption to say that it is the users responsibility to keep this cookie safe like it is the users responsibility to keep the password safe. If someone was able to steal your cookie they could likely also work out what your user agent was and copy that as well.

On the inconvenience part, many users regularly change ip address, phones change address regularly as well as sharing the same address with many other users at the same time. Also switching from wifi to mobile data. Even most home internet connections change address daily so by invalidating a session based on IP address you will likely be logging out your users multiple times per day for next to no gain. Also some privacy focused users may have their user agent set to change semi regularly.

Comment: "Even most home internet connections change address daily".  What service do you have? I've never paid for a static IP address at my home but whenever I've checked, it has lasted for ages.  In fact I don't remember ever finding it to have changed. This has been the case for years.

Comment: This has been standard on every ISP I have had in Australia. The most was one that kept it fixed for about 3 days at a time. My current ISP doesn't even give a dedicated IPv4 anymore and uses CGNAT to share one between multiple users which changes frequently.